# Win 7 Netbook refuses to ping JetDirect card (all other PCs work)

Tags: windows, networking, ping

I have an odd thing occuring here. From a Windows 7 netbook, I cannot ping an HP printer on the network, while all other machines (Win7/Vista) can. And the netbook can also ping everything else on the LAN.

Example showing that the netbook can ping 192.168.3.4 but not 3.6.

```
C:\Users\backdoor>ping w7ue1m

Pinging w7ue1m.corp.biz.co.uk [192.168.3.4] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.3.4: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.3.4: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.3.4: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.3.4: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.3.4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 7ms, Average = 3ms

C:\Users\backdoor>ping uktnprint1

Pinging uktnprint1.corp.biz.co.uk [192.168.3.6] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.3.0: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.3.0: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.3.0: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.3.0: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.3.6:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),`enter code here`
```

The IPCONFIG result for the netbook is fine.

```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.0
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Most unusual network thing I've seen in years. I must reiterate that only this netbook is having trouble pinging/printing.

Thanks, Luke

** UPDATE **

Am now on a Vista box, and here's the IPCONFIG:

```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.3
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1


Pinging uktnprint1.corp.biz.co.uk [192.168.3.6] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.3.6: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=60
```

Firewall is off. I'll look into the chance of an IP conflict because it's the only thing I can think of - compare arp caches of each machine.

Cheers!

Comment: Firewall off? rebooted the netbook and the printer? does sound odd

Comment: give me an ipconfig of a working machine?

Answer (score 2):

Is the IP of the netbook really 192.168.3.0? Is it static? Either way, that's not a valid IP.

Comment: +1, Static or not, it's not a valid IP.

Comment: @Chris, my wording made it seem like I was implying that if it was issued dynamically, then it would be ok. I've changed it.

Comment: Cheers - It's via MS DHCP but the netbook is working in all other ways. I believe .0 is fine because my s/n mask is 255.255.0.0 - see http://serverfault.com/questions/10985/is-x-y-z-0-a-valid-ip-address

Comment: Have you changed it yet, just to see?

Answer (score 0):

192.168.3.0 is a valid IP according to the RFCs, but some equipment on your network might not be configured to accept it as such.  If you assign a different IP to the offending machine and it suddenly starts working, you'll know that's the reason for sure.  Then it's just a matter of finding some brain-dead switch or whatever that doesn't adhere to the "CIDR House Rules".  Alternatively, you could configure your DHCP server to exclude the .255 and .0 addresses from its allocation pools.