# Access to local dhcp server via ssh

Tags: ssh, dhcp, local-area-network

I constructed dhcp server on centOS6 (which has a ipaddress 192.168.0.0) 
 to allocate ip address, 192.168.0.5, to other local node.

When i use "service network restart" on client node and type `ifconfig`, **the client node show their allocated ip (192.168.0.5) and subnetmask (255.255.255.0)**

However When i try to access dhcp server from client node using `ssh (hostname)@192.168.0.5`, the terminal just show "**ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.0 port 22: Network is unreachable**".

what's wrong with my concept? I can't even guess.
 Below are my configuration files.

/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-eth0 on server

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO=static
NAME="eth0"
UUID=(UUID on server)
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR0=192.168.0.0
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
HWADDR=(MAC address  on server)
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-eth0 on client

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
NAME="eth0"
UUID=(UUID on client ethernet)
ONBOOT="yes"
HWADDR=(MAC address on client ethernet)
```

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {

    host node2 {
        hardware ethernet (Mac address on client ethernet);
        fixed-address 192.168.0.5;
    }

}
```

Comment: your ip isn't valid in your netmask

http://serverfault.com/questions/10985/is-x-y-z-0-a-valid-ip-address

Comment: Whatever this is a problem with, it's **not** DHCP, because you've confirmed that the client has the right address.  Might the client be running a firewall (`iptables -L -n -v` on the client)?  Is the client running `sshd`?  Might `/etc/hosts.{allow,deny}` be causing problems?  We can't know.  But we can be fairly sure it's **not** dhcpd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `192.168.0.0` as the IP address on the router / DHCP server.

With a `/24` subnet (netmask 255.255.255.0) the first usable IP address is `192.168.0.1`.

For more information as to why [see this previous Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/10985/is-x-y-z-0-a-valid-ip-address).

Comment: You're very welcome.