# What does it mean, when remote address is x.y.0.0 in web server logs?

Tags: nginx, networking, ip

I'm trying to setup Network Policy for kubernetes, and more general question, that I have can be found [here](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/how-do-we-write-an-ingress-networkpolicy-object-in-kubernetes-so-that-calls-via-api-server-proxy-can-come-through/10142).

For the purpose of this particular question, this is the line I'm getting in nginx logs:

```
10.244.0.0 - - [18/Mar/2020:19:47:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.69.1-DEV" "192.168.80.88"
```

Note the `$remote_addr` that nginx sees, it's `10.244.0.0`. But this is not a real IP address!

I read [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/10985/is-x-y-z-0-a-valid-ip-address) and it appears, that sometimes addresses like that can be valid, but this is not standard.

For the purpose of this question, the CNI plugin that manages `10.244.0.0/16` is [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/self-managed-onprem/onpremises).

For what it worth, if I try to white-list in the [NetworkPolicy object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) `10.244.0.0/32`, the requests such as above stop coming through, which once again confirms to me that this is not the real IP. But if I white-list `10.244.0.0/16` they come through no problem.

What makes nginx think, that the request is coming from this x.y.0.0 address? How do I emulate it, say with curl?

Comment: Maybe it sees that, because that is what is coming in.  Probably would be more useful to look at tcpdump output to see if you can trace things down.

Comment: @Zoredache can you explain it more? I understand this is a TCP connection, do you mean that this is the source address in the TCP packet? If it is then the response packets should be sent back to `10.244.0.0` too, but there is nothing there?

Comment: tcpdump is not a bad idea but it would take me awhile to figure out how to run it in a nginx container inside kubernetes....

Comment: Start a netshoot container, in the same  network namespace. - https://github.com/nicolaka/netshoot That you mention kubernetes makes me wonder if that is some address related to some kind of service mesh/proxy or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10.244.0.0 is a completely valid IP address - in any subnet with the prefix  10.240.0.0/13 or shorter, or in the 10.244.0.0/31 point-to-point subnet.